# Can I purchase a PS4 in Italy and use it in Australia?

Tags: region-lock, ps4

i would like to buy a ps4 for my boyfriend that lives in australia as xmas present, but in australia preorders are for ps4 to come in february. 
i live in italy and was thinking to buy it here so i can give it to him on xmas day, but a gamer friend of mine advised me about the possibility ps4 it may not work properly because of region locks. anyone can help me out? i don't have big knowledge of gaming, but i read that as ps3 also ps4 isn't region locked for games, but only for blue ray dvds...that means he could always use non blue ray dvds, or he wouldn't be able to watch movies on ps4 at all? many thanks!!! ale

Answer (score 2):

The games should not be region-locked. The only problem he might encounter is the region-based support. When contacting support, you are prompted asking for a serial number, which tells which support center you are connected to.

Other then that he should not encounter any problems. As long as the Australians don't have any special rules. I also know some games are probably more expensive in Australia so he`ll probably benefit from setting up and EU or US SCE account too.